# Notation for equation doesn't work on SO

Tags: feature-request, support, markdown

Notation for equations doesn't work on stackoverflow.com, like it does on https://math.stackexchange.com/. As I can see both sites are use the same engine (both are part of the [stackexchage](https://stackexchange.com/)), so why I couldn't write something like `$\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$` as in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/164/why-is-the-volume-of-a-sphere-frac43-pi-r3) question?

I'm aware about [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4152/adding-support-for-math-notation) solution, but I can't see any reason to use 3rd-party solution when there's a ready one on stackexchage.com.

Comment: Sorry for the shortlived, incorrect edit. *Mea culpa*.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/latex-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

LaTeX is only enabled on Mathematics and Statical Analysis (AFAIK), but nowhere else. This is a good thing, since parsing LaTeX equations is resource intensive (on the client side). On sites where mathematical formula aren't used a lot, having LaTeX turned on is just a waste.

For simple enough equations, just use HTML, e.g. 4πr<sup>3</sup>/3.

Comment: Why? Programming related questions and answers are sometimes need formulas.

Comment: @jia, I have never come across a programming question that requires the display of complex mathematical equations.  Can you back this up with examples?

Comment: Without digging now, consider (non-trivial) questions about complexity or 3D-graphics.

Comment: @Georg: These are not the majority of questions asked on SO. You can't even find them in the top-80 tags (maybe `[algorithm]` counts, but that's still not many.)

Comment: @Kenny: I didn't say anything about proportionality - i just reacted to Aarobots *"I have never come across [...]"*.

Comment: @Georg - I agree.  I hate having to do O(n<sup>2</sup>), so it doesn't even have to be non-trivial.

Comment: @KennyTM, look "Unicode art is not enough for not-so-simple equations." [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57931/area51-se-2-0-site-specific-script-support-such-as-latex-in-beta-phase). I agree that such questions is not the majority on SO, but even one such question worth to turn this option on. I'm not sure it is a big waste of computational resources. I'm not a web developer and I like LaTeX syntax, HTML is not for me.

Comment: @jia: When I say not-so-simple equations I mean equations like http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/finding-an-addition-formula-without-trigonometry, not trivial things like O(n²). And please time how long until the page is fully loaded. And also consider the extra bandwidth it will take for something like maybe 1% of question will actually use.

Comment: But the extra-bandwidth would only be needed for that minority of questions, thus it wouldn't hurt much anyway?

Comment: @KennyTM: It is. It has to be parsed client side by Javascript, just like the (noticeably slow at times) syntax highlighter.

Comment: @Georg: How would you programmatically detect it is needed? You don't want to hardcode in tag names. And it's at least a 100kb script (broken into several files), which would add a rather significant amount of data to serve.

Comment: @Macha: If one of the requested posts uses the markup?

Comment: @Georg: How do you programmaticaly detect that it's using the markup? How do you even know it wants the markup parsed and displayed? It might be a question about making a LaTeX parser.

Comment: @Macha: The same way the script used on math.se does it? Or use special tags or whatever makes the engine happy... If it was a server-side solution its obious anyway.