# Can SE sites have custom additions to their post markup?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Support for site-specific formatting hooks in SE2.0 sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57673/support-for-site-specific-formatting-hooks-in-se2-0-sites)

We've come across a unique situation on AskUbuntu.com where we would like to - in order to simply a process - create a custom Markup Definition when creating posts and comments.

The exact specifications can be found in [this meta.AskUbuntu question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/388/the-package-installation-problem/395#395) Can additional Specs for the Markdown be added to individual SE Sites? If so what would be limits for items that could be *Markdownified*?

Lastly, how would we go about implementing the aforementioned markdown spec?

Comment: Custom addictions?